# Jest - How to test that console.error is called?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to write a unit test with jest/enzyme that tests if `console.error()` has been called in the `catch()` of a `try/catch`, but trying to do so either results in a successful test when it should be unsuccessful, or an "*Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called*" error.

**Function to test:**

```
export const playSound = (soundName, extension = 'wav') => {
  try {
    SoundPlayer.onFinishedPlaying(success => success);
    SoundPlayer.playSoundFile(soundName, extension);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error playing sound '${soundName}':`, err);
    return err;
  }
};
```

So the above takes a single argument `soundName`, which is a string, and I'm trying to test that a console error is logged when no argument is passed in.

I've most-recently tried the below, which seems to be miles off, and wrongfully returns a passed test.

```
it('fails to play sound with no method arguments', async () => {
  const consoleSpy = jest
    .spyOn(console, 'error')
    .mockImplementation(() => {});
  try {
    playSound();
    expect(consoleSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  } catch (err) {
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Your `playSound` function will never throw, because you're swallowing the exception.

you simply need this:

```
it('fails to play sound with no method arguments', async () => {
  const consoleSpy = jest
    .spyOn(console, 'error')
    .mockImplementation(() => {});
    playSound();
    expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

you can also check return value of the function call, which will be exception object.

Also if you want to check if function throws you can use

```
expect(function() { playSound(); }).toThrow();
```

but this will fail, unless you don't catch the exception or rethrow.

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried this and have tried similar before, but running the test always states that the console.error is never called

Comment: @Nick I've just tested it locally and it works, you probably have some other issue with code that you didn't show.